# Search Query in two tables

Tags: php

I want to search in two tables but there is no results im getting. this is my code.

```
$query=mysqli_query($db_connection,"SELECT * FROM db_clients JOIN db_deadreg ON db_clients.clientID=db_deadreg.clientID where fullname like '%$searchq%'");
```

Comment: You have error?  .. show error message,..... wrong result update your question add  proper data sample sample  the actual result and the expected m result

Comment: Yes when i used the example you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a concat for buil the proper filter

```
$query=mysqli_query($db_connection,
            "SELECT * 
            FROM db_clients 
            JOIN db_deadreg ON db_clients.clientID=db_deadreg.clientID 
            where fullname like concat('%' , $searchq , '%') ;  ");
```

anyway  you should not use php var in  SQL  you are at risk for sql injection, you should take a look at you sql driver for prepared statements and bindig param

eg:

```
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * 
                    FROM db_clients 
                    JOIN db_deadreg ON db_clients.clientID=db_deadreg.clientID 
                    where fullname like concat('%' , ? , '%')");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $searchq);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Highly appreciate it. but there was an error now my system says here: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website 4.0\OldClientReg.php on line 77

Comment: Im new in PHP so i really don't know how to debug the code.

Comment: Seems you are not connected  ... answer  updated  with connection too  ..  add the proper value for servername, username, password and dbname

Comment: if(isset($_POST['search'])){
  require_once 'PHP/dbhelper.php';
  $searchq=$_POST['Search'];
  $searchq= preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","", $searchq);
$query=mysqli_query($db_connection,"SELECT * FROM db_clients JOIN db_deadreg ON db_clients.clientID=db_deadreg.clientID where fullname like '%$searchq%'");

  $count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
  if($count==0){
    $output='There was no search results';